# Cloudera Manager to use hostnames not IP

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

Wherever I access Cloudera Manager via URI: http://cmhostname:7180/ it redirects to IP address http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7180/
How to change so CM uses hostname instead of DNS? DNS and resolver works well.

Answer (score 0):

Found this setting in configuration: 
Cloudera Manager > Administration > Settings > Ports and Addresses > Cloudera Manager Hostname Override